# Can't execute pm install in program

Tags: android, process

I have an android program which must use pm install, it's an enterprise application, and I want to run pm install to silently update the app for our customer

I have a method which might run pm install but nothing happened and I don't understand why? Somebody can help me?

```
private void installproperlyApp(){
        Process process = null;
        try{
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("DANS LE INSTALL COMMAND");
            os.writeBytes("pm install -r /sdcard/telegestion.apk"+"\n");

            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            String line ="";
            //on récupère l'inputStream sinon on a un deadLock pour le process
            BufferedReader inputProcess = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = inputProcess.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            //on récupère l'errorStream sinon on a un deadLock pour le process
            BufferedReader errorProcess = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = errorProcess.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            //process.waitFor();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (process != null)
                process.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack, pour une premiere question, elle est bien posée, bonne continuation!

Comment: Your code solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to run my pm command.
It was SuperSU which blocks my subprocesses executing under root acces.
In SuperSu you have a parameter to trust subprocesses, in the parameters section.
It was that parameter which is default to false which blocks my pm command. Set to true and no problems anymore.